# Need to find list of scripts that uses a certain file

Tags: perl, unix

I have a file named "performance". I need to know which scripts use this file.

Comment: This isn't generally possible without having a filesystem that logs every access. Assuming the filename would be hardcoded, wouldn't grepping through the source of possible scripts solve your problem? Tip: for a grep that recursively greps all interesting files in a directory automatically, look at [`ack`](https://metacpan.org/module/App::Ack), also known as `ack-grep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a straight forward way of listing files used by scripts. You will have to run `grep` in combination of `find` to check if the script contains the name of the file that you want to check for. Knowing the exact name of the file will help. Using words like `performance` might end up grepping files that uses that word in comments.

```
find /path/ \( -name "*.sh" -o -name "*.pl" \) -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep "performance"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on linux, then you may install and configure `auditd` to watch for accesses to a particular file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **-r option to recursively grep** through all sub-directories and find text. The syntax is as follows:

```
grep -r "performance" /dir/
```